# Keyboard not working on Cordova & AngularJS app under Windows Store platform

Tags: javascript, windows, angularjs, visual-studio, cordova

I've got a ported app from AngularJS frontend site. It works in Android & Windows Phone, but when I run it under Windows (as a Windows Store App) I can't write anything on the text boxes, even if I bring up the touch keyboard.

It's done in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 using Cordova and Angular JS.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, are you able to solve the issue? Please let me know the solution if it is already resolved.

Comment: Sorry, not yet, but upvoting the question will raise the chance of being  answered